# How to get Shared Secret in First Data Global Gateway test account

Tags: firstdata

How can i get shared secret when i have test account on first data global gateway. I am integrating my website with first data for payment processing

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below url for creation of new set of credentials in demo env:

https://firstdata.zendesk.com/entries/21510561-Global-Gateway-e4-Demo-Accounts